# How to make the snackbar take full-width in small screens?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

because of this commit:
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/commit/11695dcfa01e802797115d42c6d3d82d7657b6ab#diff-e9014062cd8e3b4344ab619966f35ef2

The snackbar doesn't take up 100% width in mobile screens. Can anyone help on how can 100% width be still given in case of small screens?

-> Before this commit, width:'auto' did the trick, but now no more.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well i figured it out, just need to pass in {width: '100%'} in the bodyStyle prop, it overrides from it.

Comment: Github issue for subscribing can be found at https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1951.  This doesn't seem to work for snackbars opened using `openFromComponent` and it seems it is fixed possibly when using just `open`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  .yourClass { width: 100%; }
}
```

Comment: It gives it inline styles, and doesn't take a class name in prop. I figured the solution and posted it. We need to use the bodyStyle prop.

Answer (score -1):

Width doesn't work for me as it does no effect not sure why. width is taking only default value though I set to 100%. I am able to apply full width using minWidth and I am using material-ui version: 0.18.7. You have to override minWidth value to apply custom width. Please find example below

```
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';

const bodyStyle = {
  border: `2px solid ${config.actualWhite}`,
  height:55,
  minWidth: 1385,
  background: config.snackbarColor,
  fontFamily: config.fontFamily,
  fontStyle: config.fontStyle,
  fontWeight: config.fontWeight,
  fontSize: config.fontSize,
  borderBottomRightRadius: 46,
  borderBottomLeftRadius: 46
}

<Snackbar
        open={this.state.open}
        message={this.state.error}
        autoHideDuration={4000}
        bodyStyle={bodyStyle}
        action="Close"
        onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
        onActionTouchTap={this.handleRequestClose}
        style={myTheme.snackbarfromTop}
      />
```